# For Searching in unsorted Array which is best - linear or binary search

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, data-structures

Why do we even say Binary Search (BS) is better than Linear Search (LS)? As when i give an unsorted array to BS and LS. We need to sort for BS. The Time complexity of all inbuild sorting algorithms are atleast O(nlogn). So Overall Time complexity to sort and find is O(nlogn+logn)=O(nlogn). As BS take O(logn). Whereas LS takes only O(n) to find a element.
So according to this statement LS is better than BS to search a element in List.

Comment: Binary search has O(logn) complexity when the input is **already sorted** and many use cases produce sorted results, so Binary Search is quite useful

Comment: Nobody claims that BS is good in an unsorted array, at least not as long as you only run 1 search and not search through the array over and over and over again at which point initially sorting may have been a better idea.

Comment: You cannot do binary search on unsorted data. Well, you can try, but results are likely to be spotty :-). It's the sorted-ness that makes it possible to decide which half of the solution space to throw away in each iteration. For example, if you're looking for 42 and the middle element is 20, how can you know whether 42 is in the first or second half if the data is unsorted?

Answer (score 3):

Sorting and using binary search makes sense when you have several searches to perform on the same array.

Let the cost of a single linear search be `a.N`, the cost of sorting `b.N.lg(N)` and the cost of a binary search `c.lg(N)`.

Now you compare `M.a.N` to `b.N.lg(N) + M.c.lg(N)` for `M` searches. The breakeven point is at

```
M = b.N.lg(N) / (a.N - c.lg(N)) ≈ b.lg(N)/a
```

which is a small multiple of `lg(N)`.